# Error Grammatical - Use of preposition A

Tags: grammar

What's wrong in this phrase?

```
Yesterday I was talking with a russian ...
```

My teacher putted like wrong "a russian".

Comment: Two quick points. 1. *a* is an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)), not a [preposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition). 2. **ask your teacher**. He knows exactly what his reasoning is, and he is paid to tell you. Why are you asking random strangers off the Internet for their wild guesses instead?

Comment: Then i need of list about meanings of abbreviations she putted in my text. Example in this case she putted CL.Meanwhile i need ask on the internet to understand my errors. :/

Comment: The past tense of strut is strutted. The past tense of put is, however, put. The word putted is the past tense of putt (what you do on the green at golf).

Comment: The past tense of *put* is *put*. So is the past participle. And the first-person singular pronoun is always capitalized, "I".

Comment: i forgot it. kkkk (what you do on the green at golf) it is funny.

Comment: ***¿"putted"?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your teacher may have expected you to use a captital letter: *Yesterday I was talking with a Russian ...*

Comment: So obvious! I have noticed a reluctance to use capital letters among a lot of foreign students, particularly at the beginning of sentences.